# How to pass an argument to a pthread thread function in C?

Tags: c, pthreads

Is it possible to pass an argument to the thread function in pthreads?
Say I create a thread:

```
int main() {
  pthread_t t1;
  pthread_create(&t1, NULL, callback, 10);
  pthread_join(t1, NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

And in `callback` I would like to just print out the `10`. My problem now is [that as per the C `pthread` API](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html), the `pthread_create()` function signature is:

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr, void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

Can I pass a pointer to an integer to the thread function and how?

Comment: What you're calling the "`callback`" is not a callback in the normal sense.  It is the thread's main function — the thread runs that function until it exits.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a variable, like:

```
  int val = 10;
  pthread_create(&t1, NULL, callback, &val);
  pthread_join(t1, NULL);
  ...
```

And in the `callback`:

```
void* callback(void *arg)
{
    int i = *(int *)arg;
    ....

    return NULL;
}
```

Note that this works because the lifetime of `val` is valid until the thread (`callback`) completes its execution as you wait with `pthread_join()`. Otherwise, you may want to allocate memory dynamically (e.g. `malloc`) and pass that object to the thread function.

Comment: I see... just trying to figure out what happens in the callback now.. more used to python.

Comment: Another option is a compound literal: `pthread_create(&t1, NULL, callback, (int []){10});`

Comment: True, @DavidRanieri, and *perhaps* useful.  There is a significant risk with that, however, in that the resulting compound literal has automatic storage duration.  That  makes it racy in exactly the same ways that passing a pointer to a local variable is.

Answer (score 0):

For a single value of integer type not wider than `intptr_t`, it possible and fairly common to cast it to a pointer in the `pthread_create` call and cast it back in the thread function:

```
int main() {
    pthread_t t1;
    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, callback, (void *) 10);
    pthread_join(t1, NULL);
    return 0;
}


void *t1(void *arg) {
    int arg_as_int = (int) arg;
    // ...
}
```

Such casting is definitely allowed, and again, is pretty conventional.

I have recently started seeing objections to this approach here on SO, however, on the basis that the C standard allows the first of those casts to produce a trap representation, and that it does not require the round-trip of `int` to `void *` to `int` to be value-preserving.  That argument characterizes the C standard correctly, but it disregards the facts that as a practical matter, the casting approach works on substantially every C implementation that supports pthreads in the first place, and that it is common enough that an implementation on which it did not work reliably would have difficulty being accepted.

Comment: OK, I don't understand how it is possible that the integer primitive `10` can be cast to a void pointer. I can see it's possible but I don't understand how that works.

Comment: @TMOTTM, a cast operator expresses a *conversion*, not a reinterpretation.  C allows integers to be converted to pointers.  But note well that the resulting pointer does not necessarily point to anything.  The pointer value itself corresponds in an unspecified (but usually very simple) way to the integer value.